# tableView не дает нажимать на ячейки

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitableview

Есть scrollView, внутри него UIView, к которому через embed segue подклчен контролер. В контроллере tablewView. (Не спрашивайте почему такая архитектура, старый проект)

Нужно чтобы таблица не скролилась, но отрисовывалась во всю высоту и помещалась полностью в scroll.

Что происходит сейчас: В контроллер, где таблица приходят данные, tableView отрисовывается на всю высоту с помощью observeValueForKeyPath где смотрится изменение высоты таблицы. 
Из этого метода забирается высота таблицы и отсылается в контроллер где скорлл, меняется высота contentSize и высота вьюхи.

После запуска мы получаем, что все нормально, все в полную высоту, НО(!) ячейки таблицы ниже какого-то значения становятся некликабельными.

Answer (score 0):

Столкнулся примерно с такой же проблемой, у меня оказалось, что на ячейке висит вьюха прозрачная (скрин в аттаче), попробуй отдебажить с помощью Debug View Hierarchy

[image: View Hierarchy]